# Improvement of a Python script | Performance

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, numpy, merge

I wrote a code. But it's very slow. The goal is to look for matches. It doesn't have to be one-on-one matches.

- I have a data frame which has about 3,600,000 entries --> "SingleDff"
- I have a data frame with about 110'000 entries --> "dfnumbers"

Now - The code tries to find out if out of these 110'000 entries you can find entries in the 3'600'000 million.

I added a counter to see how "fast" it is. After 24h I only got 11'000 entries. 10% in total

I'm looking now for ways and/or ideas how I can improve the performance of the Code.

**The Code:**

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Preparation
pathfiles = 'C:\\Python\\Data\\Input\\'
df_Files = glob.glob(pathfiles + "*.csv")

df_Files = [pd.read_csv(f, encoding='utf-8', sep=';', low_memory=False) for f in df_Files]
SingleDff = pd.concat(df_Files, ignore_index=True, sort=True) 

dfnumbers = pd.read_excel('C:\\Python\\Data\\Input\\UniqueNumbers.xlsx')


#Output
outputDf = pd.DataFrame()

SingleDff['isRelevant'] = np.nan
count = 0
max = len(dfnumbers['Korrigierter Wert'])
arrayVal = dfnumbers['Korrigierter Wert']
for txt in arrayVal:
    outputDf = outputDf.append(SingleDff[SingleDff['name'].str.contains(txt)], ignore_index = True)
    outputDf['isRelevant'] = np.where(outputDf['isRelevant'].isnull(),txt,outputDf['isRelevant'])
    count += 1

outputDf.to_csv('output_match.csv')
```

Edit:
Example of Data

In the 110'000 Data Frame I have something like this:

```
ABCD-12345-1245-T1 
ACDB-98765-001 AHHX800.0-3
```

In the huge DF i have entrys like:

```
AHSG200-B0097小样图.dwg 
MUDI-070097-0-05-00.dwg 
ABCD-12345-1245.xlsx 
ABCD-12345-1245.pdf 
ABCD-12345.xlsx
```

Now i try to find matches - For which number we can find documents

Thank you for your inputs

Comment: Can you share sample of data?

Comment: Please provide the example data in your question such that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: It doesn't matter what size data you use for the  benchmark, you don't need to share everything, just a representative sample and what you expect the output for that sample to be.

Comment: I added some example in the question @offeltoffel

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: `outputDf['isRelevant'] = np.where(outputDf['isRelevant'].isnull(),txt,outputDf['isRelevant'])`?  I have a feeling that's the slow line.

Comment: This part of the code fills the values in the new DF @DanielF

Comment: Hmm.  You could zip all your searches into a `regex` string and search that way: `outputDf = outputDf.append(SingleDff[SingleDff['name'].str.contains("|".join(arrayVal))], ignore_index = True)` (assuming that you don't break the regex character limit, in which case you'll have to do it in chunks) - but then you'll still need to loop through `outputDf` to find `'isRelevant'`.  And if multiple substrings are relevant to one input row you'll need to handle that.

Comment: Before i code up something with regex splitting, can you try `import re; re.compile("|".join(arrayVal))` and see if it throws an error?

Comment: When I use your code i got the message: error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 244098

Comment: Is there no way to avoid appending to a DataFrame? Do you have a [mcve]? Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.